# Query string URL prduces 500 internal error after removing .php extension through htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using .htaccess file on the root I removed .php extension from the url using the code below -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?foobar.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foobar/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foobar/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?foobar.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ foobar/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I have the above code in htaccess. But when ajax calls are made as below -

```
foobar.com/user/get/?a=getTaggedUsers&forumId=368
```

This produces 500 interal server error.

If I remove the last line in .htaccess file i.e -

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Then the above query-string url works fine. But now I have to put .php extension too in the url. So how to make query string work without php extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your code like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foobar\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foobar/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ foobar/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?foobar\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ foobar/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```